# Converting FeCl2 to FeSO4

Tags: recrystallization

I have FeCl2 crystals and I want to produceFeSO4.7H2O based on the reaction below:
$$\ce{FeCl2 + H2SO4 -> FeSO4 + HCl}$$
I dissolved the FeCl2 crystal in water, added equivalent amount of H2SO4 to react with all Fe (No excess) and increased the temperature to 40 C and 90 C (separate experiments). But the yield at 40 C is 70% and at 90 C is less than 30%. Any idea how I can improve the yield?

Comment: So what is the relationship between yield and temperature? You thought here would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a solubility issue, ferrous sulfate is more soluble at higher T. Try small excess of sulfuric acid and lower temperature. Add a pinch of bicarbonate to work under a CO2 atmosphere to prevent air oxidation of the ferrous salt to a ferric salt. Check the solubilities of everything to ascertain the limits.

Comment: Recrystallizing Fe(II) salts from water is extremely ungrateful task. They are oxidized by air too readily.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik
 At room temperature it did not work, so I am confused.

Comment: You better produce $\ce{FeSO4}$ by the reaction of metallic iron powder on sulfuric acid $\ce{H2SO4}$